# [restlet ]TruncatedChunkException:

Tags: restlet

For my project (http://snooze.inria.fr/) i have dependencies on java library restlet.

If I set up the dependency to restlet 2.2-SNAPSHOT a TruncatedChunkException when visualizing the hierarchy on the client (it's a big json received form the system)
If I set up the dependency to restlet 2.1-SNAPSHOT i have no error, everything looks fine.

Do you know why ?

Best Regards,

Matt

ps : 
here the stack trace :

```
org.restlet - Unable to convert a [application/json] representation into an object of class org.inria.myriads.snoozecommon.communication.groupmanager.repository.GroupLeaderRepositoryInformation
org.apache.http.TruncatedChunkException: Truncated chunk ( expected size: 2085; actual size: 1997)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:182)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:186)
[...]
```

Here an example of json : (it's basically a list of hosts hosting vm's with their attributes)

```
groupManagerDescriptions":[{"id":"4d415a3b-579d-4fcd-8700-f2d4a2242401","listenSettings":{"controlDataAddress":{"address":"127.0.0.1","port":6001},"monitoringDataAddress":{"address":"127.0.0.1","port":7000}},"localControllers":{"52a3e5b1-2354-4d67-ab52-c6b38efd20c5":{"id":"52a3e5b1-2354-4d67-ab52-c6b38efd20c5","controlDataAddress":{"address":"127.0.0.1","port":6003},"status":"ACTIVE","hypervisorSettings":{"port":16509,"driver":"qemu","transport":"tcp","migration":{"method":"forceunsafe","timeout":60}},"totalCapacity":[4.0,3958916.0,131072.0,131072.0],"wakeupSettings":{"driver":"IPMI","options":"-I lanplus -H BMC_IP -U user -P password"},"hostname":"mafalda","virtualMachineMetaData":{"debian1":{"status":"RUNNING","virtualMachineLocation":{"virtualMachineId":"debian1","localControllerControlDataAddress":{"address":"127.0.0.1","port":6003},"localControllerId":"52a3e5b1-2354-4d67-ab52-c6b38efd20c5"},"usedCapacity":{},"requestedCapacity":[1.0,512000.0,12800.0,12800.0],"ipAddress":"192.168.122.2","errorCode":"UNKNOWN","groupManagerControlDataAddress":{"address":"127.0.0.1","port":6001},"xmlRepresentation":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><domain type=\"kvm\">  <name>debian1</name>  <memory>512000</memory>  <vcpu>1</vcpu>  <os>    <type arch=\"x86_64\" machine=\"pc-0.12\">hvm</type>    <boot dev=\"hd\"/>  </os>  <features>    <acpi/>    <apic/>    <pae/>  </features>  <clock offset=\"utc\"/>  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>  <devices>    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>    <disk device=\"disk\" type=\"file\">      <driver name=\"qemu\" type=\"qcow2\"/>      <source file=\"/home/msimonin/Images-VM/Snooze-images/imgs/debian1.qcow2\"/>      <target bus=\"virtio\" dev=\"vda\"/>      <address bus=\"0x00\" domain=\"0x0000\" function=\"0x0\" slot=\"0x05\" type=\"pci\"/>    </disk>    <controller index=\"0\" type=\"ide\">      <address bus=\"0x00\" domain=\"0x0000\" function=\"0x1\" slot=\"0x01\" type=\"pci\"/>    </controller>    <interface type=\"bridge\">      <mac address=\"54:56:c0:a8:7a:2\"/>      <source bridge=\"virbr0\"/>    </interface>    <serial type=\"pty\">      <target port=\"0\"/>    </serial>    <console type=\"pty\">      <target port=\"0\" type=\"serial\"/>    </console>    <graphics autoport=\"yes\" listen=\"0.0.0.0\" port=\"-1\" type=\"vnc\"/>    <input bus=\"usb\" type=\"tablet\"/>    <input bus=\"ps2\" type=\"mouse\"/>    <memballoon model=\"virtio\">      <address bus=\"0x00\" domain=\"0x0000\" function=\"0x0\" slot=\"0x06\" type=\"pci\"/>    </memballoon>  </devices></domain>"},"debian3":{"status":"RUNNING","virtualMachineLocation":{"virtualMachineId":"debian3","localControllerControlDataAddress":{"address":"127.0.0.1","port":6003},"localControllerId":"52a3e5b1-2354-4d67-ab52-c6b38efd20c5"},"usedCapacity":{},"requestedCapacity":[1.0,128000.0,12800.0,12800.0],"ipAddress":"192.168.122.4","errorCode":"UNKNOWN","groupManagerControlDataAddress":{"address":"127.0.0.1","port":6001},"xmlRepresentation":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><domain type=\"kvm\">  <name>debian3</name>  <memory>128000</memory>  <vcpu>1</vcpu>  <os>    <type arch=\"x86_64\" machine=\"pc-0.12\">hvm</type>    <boot dev=\"hd\"/>  </os>  <features>    <acpi/>    <apic/>    <pae/>  </features>  <clock offset=\"utc\"/>  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>  <devices>    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>    <disk device=\"disk\" type=\"file\">      <driver name=\"qemu\" type=\"qcow2\"/>      <source file=\"/home/msimonin/Images-VM/Snooze-images/imgs/debian3.qcow2\"/>      <target bus=\"virtio\" dev=\"vda\"/>      <address bus=\"0x00\" domain=\"0x0000\" function=\"0x0\" slot=\"0x05\" type=\"pci\"/>    </disk>    <controller index=\"0\" type=\"ide\">      <address bus=\"0x00\" domain=\"0x0000\" function=\"0x1\" slot=\"0x01\" type=\"pci\"/>    </controller>    <interface type=\"b"
[DEBUG] |févr. 04 10:44:20| [Thread-1] http.wire  - << "ridge\">      <mac address=\"54:56:c0:a8:7a:4\"/>      <source bridge=\"virbr0\"/>    </interface>    <serial type=\"pty\">      <target port=\"0\"/>    </serial>    <console type=\"pty\">      <target port=\"0\" type=\"serial\"/>    </console>    <graphics autoport=\"yes\" listen=\"0.0.0.0\" port=\"-1\" type=\"vnc\"/>    <input bus=\"usb\" type=\"tablet\"/>    <input bus=\"ps2\" type=\"mouse\"/>    <memballoon model=\"virtio\">      <address bus=\"0x00\" domain=\"0x0000\" function=\"0x0\" slot=\"0x06\" type=\"pci\"/>    </memballoon>  </devices></domain>"}},"assignedVirtualMachines":[]},"c56846f6-fd61-47d5-9f68-0fd2772aac4d":{"id":"c56846f6-fd61-47d5-9f68-0fd2772aac4d","controlDataAddress":{"address":"127.0.0.1","port":6004},"status":"ACTIVE","hypervisorSettings":{"port":16510,"driver":"qemu","transport":"tcp","migration":{"method":"forceunsafe","timeout":60}},"totalCapacity":[4.0,3958916.0,131072.0,131072.0],"wakeupSettings":{"driver":"IPMI","options":"-I lanplus -H BMC_IP -U user -P password"},"hostname":"mafalda","virtualMachineMetaData":{"debian2":{"status":"RUNNING","virtualMachineLocation":{"virtualMachineId":"debian2","localControllerControlDataAddress":{"address":"127.0.0.1","port":6004},"localControllerId":"c56846f6-fd61-47d5-9f68-0fd2772aac4d"},"usedCapacity":{},"requestedCapacity":[2.0,123456.0,12800.0,12800.0],"ipAddress":"192.168.122.3","errorCode":"UNKNOWN","groupManagerControlDataAddress":{"address":"127.0.0.1","port":6001},"xmlRepresentation":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?><domain type=\"kvm\">  <name>debian2</name>  <uuid>0f476e56-67ea-11e1-858e-00216a972a37</uuid>  <memory>123456</memory>  <vcpu>2</vcpu>  <os>    <type arch=\"x86_64\" machine=\"pc-0.12\">hvm</type>    <boot dev=\"hd\"/>  </os>  <features>    <acpi/>    <apic/>    <pae/>  </features>  <clock offset=\"utc\"/>  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>  <devices>    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>    <disk device=\"disk\" type=\"file\">      <driver name=\"qemu\" type=\"qcow2\"/>      <source file=\"/home/msimonin/Images-VM/Snooze-images/imgs/debian2.qcow2\"/>      <target bus=\"virtio\" dev=\"vda\"/>      <address bus=\"0x00\" domain=\"0x0000\" function=\"0x0\" slot=\"0x05\" type=\"pci\"/>    </disk>    <controller index=\"0\" type=\"ide\">      <address bus=\"0x00\" domain=\"0x0000\" function=\"0x1\" slot=\"0x01\" type=\"pci\"/>    </controller>    <interface type=\"bridge\">      <mac address=\"54:56:c0:a8:7a:3\"/>      <source bridge=\"virbr0\"/>    </interface>    <serial type=\"pty\">      <target port=\"0\"/>    </serial>    <console type=\"pty\">      <target port=\"0\" type=\"serial\"/>    </console>    <graphics autoport=\"yes\" listen=\"0.0.0.0\" port=\"-1\" type=\"vnc\"/>    <input bus=\"usb\" type=\"tablet\"/>    <input bus=\"ps2\" type=\"mouse\"/>    <memballoon model=\"virtio\">      <address bus=\"0x00\" domain=\"0x0000\" function=\"0x0\" slot=\"0x06\" type=\"pci\"/>    </memballoon>  </devices></domain>"}},"assignedVirtualMachines":[]}},"heartbeatAddress":{"address":"225.4.5.6","port":10000},"hostname":"mafalda","summaryInformation":{"1359971059986":{"timeStamp":1359971059986,"usedCapacity":[4.0,763456.0,38400.0,38400.0],"requestedCapacity":[4.0,763456.0,38400.0,38400.0],"activeCapacity":[8.0,7917832.0,262144.0,262144.0],"passiveCapacity":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],"legacyIpAddresses":[]},"1359971056979":{"timeStamp":1359971056979,"usedCapacity":[4.0,763456.0,38400.0,38400.0],"requestedCapacity":[4.0,763456.0,38400.0,38400.0],"activeCapacity":[8.0,7917832.0,262144.0,262144.0],"passiveCapacity":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],"legacyIpAddresses":[]},"1359971053975":{"timeStamp":1359971053975,"usedCapacity":[3.0,635456.0,25600.0,25600.0],"requestedCapacity":[3.0,635456.0,25600.0,25600.0],"activeCapacity":[8.0,7917832.0,262144.0,262144.0],"passiveCapacity":[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],"legacyIpAddresses":[]},""
```

[...]